# Go Gin Webframework - Pass Values from Pointer Array to the template

Tags: go, go-gin

I want to display the values from the pointer array inside a .html template file instead of only the memory addresses.

Is there a way using Gin automatically parsing the pointers and deference it in side the .H function so I can display the actual values inside the html?

```
func initRoutes() {
    router.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        prices, err := client.NewListPricesService().Do(context.Background())
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Print(err)
        }
        c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.html", gin.H{
            "title": "aa website",
            "data":  prices, //array of pointers I want the values in html tho
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: You could have the pointer price type implement the `Stringer` interface, if I'm not mistaken that should be enough. Or you can use `range` inside the template and format the individual price elements however you like. https://go.dev/play/p/RpIO34fM601

Comment: my solution now was a new slice inside the GET and range over the pointers and append the dereferenced values and use that inside the .H but I thought maybe there is some more elegant or automatic way in golang. Thank you!